# Confusion about irreps of $SU(N)$: is the "color charge" the same as spin 1?

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, quarks, color-charge

Sorry if the question is too silly or not well stated, I am happy to clarify any point. Also, my presuppositions can be wrong.

Consider a system of spin-$s$ particles: their spin operators $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ are generators of the group $SU(2)$, in particular they are a $(2s+1)$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$. This means that I can transform a spin state $|\psi_0\rangle$ into another spin state $|\psi_1\rangle$ by applying a matrix which belongs to the irreducible representation, i.e. something like $|\psi_1\rangle = U|\psi_0\rangle$, where $U=\exp\{i\theta\, \vec{n}\cdot \vec{S}\}$.

We can now consider the fundamental irreducible representation of the group $SU(2s+1)$: we can still transform an initial state $|\psi_0\rangle$ into another $|\psi_1\rangle$ by applying to the latter the exact same matrix $U$, that now should be written in terms of the generators of $SU(2s+1)$.

So my question is: why can't we say that a spin $s$ particle transforms with the fundamental irreducible representation of $SU(2s+1)$ and instead we say that it transforms with a $(2s+1)$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$?
In other words, what is precisely the difference between saying that a particle has a spin $1$ and saying that it has a "color charge"?

**EDIT**
I explain the origin of my confusion: if I want to describe a system of fermionic atoms with angular momentum $s$ hopping on a lattice, I have an Hamiltonian like
$$H=-t\sum_{ij,\sigma} c^{\dagger}_{i\sigma} c_{j\sigma} + \mathrm{h.c.}$$
(where $c$ and $c^{\dagger}$ are fermionic annihilation and creation operators) which features a $U(1)\times SU(2s+1)$ symmetry generated by the operators $S_{\sigma\rho} = \sum_i c^{\dagger}_{i\sigma} c_{i\rho}$.
I am confused by the fact that angular momentum is associated to $SU(2)$, but the symmetry group of my Hamiltonian is $SU(2s+1)$. I would like to understand what is the role of the group $SU(2)$ here.

Comment: A real spin one vector will stay real after an SU(2) transformation, but not after an SU(3) one, no?

Comment: You do not have a $j$ index in your $H$.  Is this just a typo?  Basically your $H$ is diagonal.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yep, sorry, just a typo

Answer (score 2):

It is true that, given a $(2s+1)\times (2s+1)$ matrix representation of $S_x,S_y,S_z$, then $e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot\vec S}$ will be a $(2s+1)$-dimensional unitary matrix and thus in $SU(2s+1)$, but not all $SU(2s+1)$ elements are of the form $e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot\vec S}$.

Indeed $e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot\vec S}$ still depends on only $3$ parameters but transformations in $SU(2s+1)$ will in general depend on $(2s+1)^2-1$ parameters, indicating again that some transformations in $SU(2s+1)$ will not be in $SU(2)$.

As a specific example, consider the Hermitian matrices
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&0&-1\\
0&-1&0\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
You can verify that neither $A$ nor $B$ is a linear combination of the $3$-dimensional matrix representations of $S_x,S_y, S_z$, yet they are legitimate Hermitian matrices and thus in $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.   Thus, there is no way
$$
e^{-i\alpha A}= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (\alpha ) & 0 & i \sin (\alpha
   ) \\
 0 & e^{i \alpha } & 0 \\
 i \sin (\alpha ) & 0 & \cos (\alpha
   ) \\
\end{array}
\right)\, ,\qquad 
e^{-i \beta B}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos ^2\left(\frac{\beta
   }{2}\right) & \frac{i \sin (\beta
   )}{\sqrt{2}} & \sin
   ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)
   \\
 \frac{i \sin (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} &
   \cos (\beta ) & -\frac{i \sin
   (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\beta
   }{2}\right) & -\frac{i \sin
   (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} & \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)
   \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
can be in $SU(2)$ although it will be in $SU(3)$.

---

If I understand correctly, you have two kinds of indices here: $i$ and $\sigma$.  If you have
$$
S_{ij}=\sum_{\sigma}a^\dagger_{i\sigma}a_{j\sigma}, \qquad 1\le i,j\le r
$$
then $S_{ij}$ is in $\mathfrak{u}(r)$.  On the other hand, if you use instead
$$
{\cal S}_{\sigma\rho}=\sum_{i}a^\dagger_{i\sigma}a_{i\rho}, \qquad 1\le \sigma,\rho \le q
$$
then ${\cal S}_{\sigma\rho}$ is in $\mathfrak{u}(q)$.  This is an example of unitary-unitary duality.  Basically, you are really working with $\mathfrak{u}(r\times q)$ and $\mathfrak{u}(r)$ and $\mathfrak{u}(q)$ as subalgebras of $\mathfrak{u}(r\times q)$.

Thus, your color charge could enter via the range of the $\sigma,\rho$ indices and would be in $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ if $q=2$.  The ${\cal S}_{\sigma\rho}$ actually commute with $S_{ij}$, which are in $\mathfrak{u}(r)$ where $1\le i,j\le r$.

You will find additional details on unitary-unitary duality in Section V of

> Rowe, D.J., Carvalho, M.J. and Repka, J., 2012. Dual pairing of symmetry and dynamical groups in physics. *Reviews of Modern Physics*, *84*(2), p.711.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that not all $(2s+1)\times (2s+1)$ matrices are in $SU(2)$, but what confuses me is the difference between a spin-1 particle and a particle with color charge. They both are described by states in a 3-dimensional Hilbert space, so where does the group paly a role? I am probably missing something at a very basic level...

Comment: @Matteo It's a matter of comparing generators that will transform your states under color charge with the generators of $su(2)$.   Clearly the dimension of the Hilbert space is not enough to pin down the symmetry group (or its Lie algebra) so unless you can make statements about this group (or its Lie algebra) then you don't have much to go on.  For instance, do you have generators of the type $A$ or $B$ in your possible transformations between states in your Hilbert space?

Comment: Ok, so for example if I choose $\alpha=\pi/2$ in the first matrix and I apply that matrix to the state $|r\rangle = (1,0,0)$, I get $(0,0,i)=i|b\rangle$, which I cannot obtain by applying an $SU(2)$ matrix, right?

Comment: It happens to be possible for this *specific* value of $\alpha$ to find an $SU(2)$ element that will do this *specific* transformation, but if you choose $\alpha=\pi/4$ instead then I don't think there is a corresponding $SU(2)$ transformation (assuming I did not mess up my computation).

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand the maths, but the physics is still a little obscure. I have edited the question providing a little bit of context of the problem that I am studying. Could you please add some explanation about that?

Comment: @Matteo I don't think SU2 plays any role in your problem.  The $r^2$ combination $a_i^\dagger a_j$, with $1\le i,j\le r$ span the Lie algebra $u(r)$.  You just have a version of this obtained by summing over sites, but this doesn't change the basic result.  In particular, you can generate my matrices $A$ and $B$ with $r=3$ using your operators.  Presumably for instance $A_{13}$ is related to $a^\dagger_1 a_3$. (summed over $\sigma$s) and this type of entry you cannot get from $S_+$ in $s=1$ since $S_+$ is band diagonal connecting only neighboring states.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150008/discussion-between-matteo-and-zerothehero).